# How to tab an output as per a counter?

Tags: python

I'm trying to print a sentence ten times or so (as per what count is given in `range()`), but I want the first sentence tabbed once, the second sentence tabbed twice, etc...

Here is my code:

```
count = 0

for i in range(10):
    print("\t*countPython is fun")
    count += 1
```

Currently I get the output as below which is not something I want:

```
*countPython is fun
*countPython is fun
*countPython is fun
*countPython is fun
*countPython is fun
*countPython is fun
*countPython is fun
```

I understand that this is something to be done in the `print()` function, but I don't get it correct. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: there is no need to have an external counter, your variable `i` is increasing from 0 to 9

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`* count` must be outside the string:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(("\t"*count) + "Python is fun")
    count += 1
```

Comment: thank you ugoren for the reply. It was the "+" I was missing.

Comment: It would be nice of you to accept the answer, if it works for you.

Comment: there is no need to have an external counter, the variable `i` is increasing from 0 to 9

Answer (score 1):

As julio.alegria commented on your question, `range()` eliminates the need for an external counter:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(('\t' * (i + 1)) + 'Python is fun')
```

Answer (score 1):

In py3, `print()` takes comma separated arguments, and prints them with the default `' '` argument for `sep`.

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    print('\t' * i, 'Py3 has a great print function!')
```

Or

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    #removes space after tab(s) 
    print('\t' * i, 'Py3 has a great print function!', sep='')
```

Comment: Missing quotes around the tab character, no?

Comment: @DSM whatever are you talking about? `<darts eyes around suspiciously>` `;)`